# Custom UserControl with templating

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a reusable control that can show a list of entered values, and ability to delete values. The way it is presented should be based on a "DisplayMemberPath", or be templated. This is close to what I'm trying to achieve.

[![Inspiration][1]][1]

So far I have created a custom UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.CriteriaView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Padding="2,2,0,0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
                            BorderThickness="0.6"
                            Margin="0,0,2,2">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="{Binding .}"
                                   Padding="0"
                                   Margin="1" />
                            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
                                    Margin="1">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{DynamicResource RemoveIcon}" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBlock"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CriteriaView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CriteriaView : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemsSource",
            typeof (IEnumerable),
            typeof (CriteriaView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource {
            get { return (IEnumerable)this.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DisplayMemberPath",
            typeof (string),
            typeof (CriteriaView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string DisplayMemberPath {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AddCommand",
            typeof (ICommand),
            typeof (CriteriaView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

        public ICommand AddCommand {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(AddCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AddCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "RemoveCommand",
            typeof (ICommand),
            typeof (CriteriaView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

        public ICommand RemoveCommand {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(RemoveCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RemoveCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public CriteriaView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            this.ItemsControl.ItemsSource = this.ItemsSource;
        }

        private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (this.AddCommand != null && (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Tab))
                this.AddCommand.Execute(this.TextBlock.Text);

        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (RemoveCommand == null) return;
            var no = (sender as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as int?;
            RemoveCommand.Execute(no);
        }
    }
}
```

And desired usage

```
<view:CriteriaView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Criteria.SerialNumbers}"
                   AddCommand="{Binding AddCommand}"
                   RemoveCommand="{Binding RemoveCommand}"
                   DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName"/>
```

And have the UserControl handle the rest. Where I fall short is incorporating a "DisplayMemberPath" into a template the ItemsControl can use.

Any clues on how to do this?

/Edit: Solution

I created a custom control like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyNamespace.Views
{
    public class CriteriaView : ItemsControl
    {
        static CriteriaView()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(CriteriaView),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CriteriaView)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AddCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(CriteriaView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

        public ICommand AddCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(AddCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AddCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "RemoveCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(CriteriaView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

        public ICommand RemoveCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(RemoveCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RemoveCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        private TextBox _box;

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            this._box = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_AddElementTextBox") as TextBox;
            if (this._box != null) this._box.PreviewKeyDown += this.UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown;

            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.AddCommand != null
                && (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Tab)) {
                var preCount = this.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count();
                this.AddCommand.Execute(this._box.Text);
                var postCount = this.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count();
                if (postCount != preCount) this._box.Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Views">
    <views:DisplayMemberPathConverter x:Key="DisplayMemberPathConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type views:CriteriaView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type views:CriteriaView}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
                            BorderThickness="0.6"
                            Margin="0,0,2,2">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0"
                                          Padding="2,2,0,0"
                                          ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
                                                BorderThickness="0.6"
                                                Margin="0,0,2,2">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Label Padding="0"
                                                       Margin="1">
                                                    <Label.Content>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisplayMemberPathConverter}">
                                                            <Binding Path="."/>
                                                            <Binding Path="DisplayMemberPath"
                                                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:CriteriaView}"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </Label.Content>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Button Margin="1"
                                                        Command="{Binding RemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:CriteriaView}}"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                                    <Button.Template>
                                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                                            <Image Source="{DynamicResource RemoveIcon}" />
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Button.Template>
                                                </Button>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_AddElementTextBox"
                                     Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the converter

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyNamespace.Views
{
    public class DisplayMemberPathConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length != 2) return null;
            var prop = values[1] as string;
            var obj = values[0];
            if (prop == null || obj == null) return obj;

            var result = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop)?.GetValue(obj, null);
            return result ?? obj;

        }
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

And the usage is straight forward

```
<view:CriteriaView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Criteria.SerialNumbers}"
                   AddCommand="{Binding AddSerial}"
                   RemoveCommand="{Binding RemoveSerial}"
                   DisplayMemberPath="." />
```

Comment: I recommend to make an CustomControl deriving from ItemsControl instead of an UserControl. Benefits are, you can Theme it plus you can use {TemplateBinding}

Comment: I did look into that, but I couldn't find much on adding a textbox to it. Do you have any code snippets or better, some documentation. What I can find on MSDN didn't seem helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved you code from a UserControl to a CustomControl so you can play around with TemplateBinding:

The Control:

```
public class CriteriaView : ItemsControl {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AddCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AddCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(CriteriaView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public ICommand AddCommand {
      get {
        return (ICommand)GetValue(AddCommandProperty);
      }
      set {
        SetValue(AddCommandProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "RemoveCommand",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(CriteriaView),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public ICommand RemoveCommand {
      get {
        return (ICommand)GetValue(RemoveCommandProperty);
      }
      set {
        SetValue(RemoveCommandProperty, value);
      }
    }

    private TextBox _box;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
      this._box = this.GetTemplateChild("TextBlock") as TextBox;
      this._box.PreviewKeyDown += this.UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown;
      base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
      if (this.AddCommand != null && (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Tab))
        this.AddCommand.Execute(this._box.Text);

    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      if (RemoveCommand == null)
        return;
      var no = (sender as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as int?;
      RemoveCommand.Execute(no);
    }

  }
```

The Style (Move to Generic!)

```
<Style TargetType="xx:CriteriaView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="xx:CriteriaView">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Padding="2,2,0,0">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <TextBox x:Name="TextBlock" Grid.Row="1" Text="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

The Usage:

```
<xx:CriteriaView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Criteria.SerialNumbers}"
               AddCommand="{Binding AddCommand}"
               RemoveCommand="{Binding RemoveCommand}"
               DisplayMemberPath="{Binding YOURPROPERTY">
                <xx:CriteriaView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
                    BorderThickness="0.6"
                    Margin="0,0,2,2">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="{Binding .}" 
                           Padding="0"
                           Margin="1"/>
                                <Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            Margin="1">
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="{DynamicResource RemoveIcon}" />
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xx:CriteriaView.ItemTemplate>
            </xx:CriteriaView>
```

As you can see, some of your DependencyProps are Obsolete as we derive from ItemsControls and simply give it an ControlTemplate. Now you can you can use your DisplayMememberPath of the bound Elements.

Comment: So far so good, but the usage is far from ideal. the ItemTemplate will be repeated 10+ places, with only the property shown being different. Can that be put in the style?

Comment: I dont understand your Question. It's an Itemtemplate. It is applied to each Item in your Itemssource. Feel free to edit the style as it suits for you. I basically copied your code and moved it to an CustomControl to show you the benefits of TemplateBinding

Comment: Further more, you can put your ItemTemplate directly in the ControlTemplate. So you dont have to do it where you use it

Comment: Putting it in the ControlTemplate was what I meant. I have created a solution, and will update the post with it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge your Template's add a DependencyProperty "DisplayMemberPath" to your UserControl and then use a CustomValueConverter for your Label Content.

the Value Converter

```
public class DisplayMemberPathConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">YourItemSourceItem</param>
        /// <param name="targetType"></param>
        /// <param name="parameter">DisplayMemberPath</param>
        /// <param name="culture"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.GetType().GetProperty(parameter.ToString()).GetValue(value, null);
        }
    }
```

and  in your ItemsControl ItemTemplate do something like this

```
 <Label Content="{Binding CriteriaView, 
    ConverterParameter=DisplayMemberPath, 
    Converter={StaticResource DisplayMemberPathConverter}}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand,ElementName=CriteriaView}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding CriteriaView}"
                                Margin="1">
```

Edit do the Binding in your UserControl like this and then in your ViewModel just remove the entry from your Collection :

```
public ICommand RemoveCommand => new DelegateCommand<object>(OnRemoveCommand);

        private void OnRemoveCommand(object obj)
        {
            myCriteriaViewCollection.Remove(obj as CriteriaView);
        }
```

Comment: That works for displaying the correct property, but I still cannot bind anything to a supplied RemoveCommand, as it is in a template and I it cannot bind to the individual elements.

Comment: I was misinterpreting it. I have updated the question to reflect the current issues, namely a binding in a template, that needs data from a property in the codebehind.